# WordPress/Drupal programming questions

Tags: discussion, wordpress-se

Quick question -- I post a lot of WordPress-related programming questions on SO (Not just simply WP-related questions), but are these better to ask on the WP-specific SO site?

Ultimately, I'm asking: do the benefits of a programmer-specific audience outweigh the benefits of a WordPress-specific audience when asking WordPress programming questions?

Same goes for Drupal programming questions on SO and the Drupal-specific site nearing beta stage on Area 51 -- another issue is whether you dilute the community of people following a tag on SO when you create a CMS-specific community. Basically, are programming questions at all inappropriate on the CMS-specific sites, or CMS-specific questions inappropriate on SO (when a CMS-specific SE site already exists)?

I really just want to post questions where they'll a. Help grow the appropriate community b. Be seen by the most relevant audience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it. Post some questions on [the WordPress SE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/), and see what answers you get.

I've been active there since the start, and I think it is a benefit to have a separate site. Because we can accept questions that would be barely on-topic on SO (questions about themes, or specific configuration in the GUI, ...), we can group some very smart WordPress people on the site, who would otherwise be distributed over SO, WebApps, Webmasters, ...

There are some questions that we should consider off-topic, [to prevent ourselves from losing our focus](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100/should-we-allow-general-php-css-html-questions-if-theyre-contextually-related-to). But we've managed this quite well in the past, with subtle hints to re-ask (a part of) a question on SO, Webmasters or WebApps, and return to us when you know *what* you want to do, and now need to know *how* to do this in WordPress.

Comment: This works. One issue I've had with this idea is that it somewhat stratifies generalist expertise amongst people who don't visit all of the Stack sites, but on the other hand, I also just noticed everything's aggregated on StackExchange.com, so maybe I should just start using that more. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

They wouldn't go on webapps.stackexchange.com, since all but one questions tagged "Drupal" there has been closed (and the one that hasn't has no answers).

[Webmasters.se](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com) seems to have a [fairly active Drupal tag](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drupal).  These all seem to be related to the configuration of a Drupal installation.

SO also has an active [Drupal tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drupal), and these mostly seem to be about creating modules or extracting information from the Drupal DB.

So I'd probably say that if your question is about how to use Drupal, then it would go on Webmasters.SE, and if it's about how to customize Drupal programmatically, it would probably go on SO.  Of course, if/when Drupal.SE goes live, this may change dramatically.

(These observations appear to generally hold true for the Wordpress tag as well)